# Python-Fu fails on directory selection (PF_DIRNAME)

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu

Using Python-Fu/gimpfu, I was able to register a plugin and run it from the Script-Fu console.

[image]

But I could not run the plugin from the created GUI menu item.

[image]

No matter which entry I selected from either directory drop-down menu, I would receive these errors:

1. pythonw.exe has stopped working (Close program)
2. GIMP Message: Plug-in crashed: "batch_scale.py"
3. GIMP Message: Unable to run GimpPdbProgress callback

GIMP version: 2.8.18

Plug-in code (some functions omitted for brevity):

```
import os
from gimpfu import *

# Copy to ~/.gimp-<version>/plug-ins
# Launch GIMP
# Should register a function named python-fu-batch-scale
# Run the function from Filters > Script-Fu > Console

def loadImage(sourceFile):
    if isJPEG(sourceFile):
        return pdb.file_jpeg_load(sourceFile, sourceFile)
    if isPNG(sourceFile):
        return pdb.file_png_load(sourceFile, sourceFile)

def saveImage(outputFile, image):
    drawable = pdb.gimp_image_get_active_drawable(image)
    if isJPEG(outputFile):
        saveJPEG(outputFile, image, drawable)
    if isPNG(outputFile):
        savePNG(outputFile, image, drawable)

def scaleImage(image, maxWidth, maxHeight):
    width = pdb.gimp_image_width(image)
    height = pdb.gimp_image_height(image)
    aspectRatio = width * 1.0 / height
    if aspectRatio >= 1.0:
        # horizontal
        newWidth = min(width, maxWidth)
        newHeight = newWidth / aspectRatio
        pdb.gimp_image_scale(image, newWidth, newHeight)
    else:
        # vertical
        newHeight = min(height, maxHeight)
        newWidth = newHeight * aspectRatio
        pdb.gimp_image_scale(image, newWidth, newHeight)

def run(sourceFolder, outputFolder, maxWidth, maxHeight):

    if not os.path.exists(outputFolder):
        os.makedirs(outputFolder)

    filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(sourceFolder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(sourceFolder, f))]
    for filename in filenames:
        sourceFile = os.path.join(sourceFolder, filename)
        outputFile = os.path.join(outputFolder, filename)
        image = loadImage(sourceFile)
        scaleImage(image, maxWidth, maxHeight)
        saveImage(outputFile, image)

register(
    "batch_scale",
    "Scales a folder of images (JPEG or PNG)",
    "<help>",
    "<author>",
    "<license>",
    "<date>",
    "<Toolbox>/Xtns/Languages/Python-Fu/_Scale Images",
    "",
    [
        (PF_DIRNAME, "sourceFolder", "Source directory", ""),
        (PF_DIRNAME, "outputFolder", "Output directory", ""),
        (PF_INT, "maxWidth", "Maximum width", 1600),
        (PF_INT, "maxHeight", "Maximum height", 900)
    ],
    [],
    run
)

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a similar problem on Linux, the plugin dies horribly as soon as I click on the directory selectors. There is however a workaround: give a default directory (it seems it doesn't even need to be  valid directory, at least for on the Linux version):

```
(PF_DIRNAME, "outputFolder", "Output directory", "/tmp"),
```

#### PS:

- While I applaud your foray in Gimp python scripting, you can do the same thing with one invokation of ImageMagick's [`convert` command](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).
- You can also test your Python scripts in the Python-fu console
- In this 21st century, nobody registers scripts with menus in `<Toolbox>/Xtns/Languages/Python-Fu/`, you must be looking at very old docs.

Comment: Woo hoo! Giving a non-empty default value worked on Windows as well. And re: your PSes, thank you - very helpful.